# PHP scan directory folders first then remaining files

Tags: php

I'm looking for a function that can scan a directory and return an array containing the result by folder first then the remaining files, thanks in advance.

```html
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scanDir($dir);
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
    listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
   }
   else
   {
    echo  $ff . "<br>";
   }
        }
    }
}
listFolderFiles('..');
```

This code will recursively scan folders however i need to return folders before files.

Comment: the wording of this question is not clear - can you give a sample directory and file structure and expected output?

Comment: Something like [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)?

Comment: `scandir` + `usort`?

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists. You'll have get whatever comes back from whichever method you'll use, and sort it yourself

Comment: No idea why this is "on hold as off-topic", i had a programming issue, came here and got it resolved by etherous???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one definitely works

```
function file_sort ($a,$b)
{
    return ($cmp = is_dir($b) - is_dir($a)) ? $cmp : strcmp($a, $b);
}

function directories_first ($path)
{
    $files = array ();
    $dh  = opendir($path);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
    {
        if($filename=='.' || $filename=='..')
            continue;
        $files[] = rtrim($path, '/').'/'.ltrim($filename, '/');
    }

    usort($files,'file_sort');

    return $files;
}
```

Comment: Tried this and didnt work :/

Comment: When i use print_r($files); the list does not seem to have any order

Comment: You may be using the version before I added in the alphabetical sorting

Comment: Hint: `return is_dir($a) - is_dir($b);`

Comment: That would discount alphabetical ordering again. Also, I hate to treat booleans as numbers. It just seems like bad form

Comment: `if ($dir = is_dir($a) - is_dir($b)) return $dir; else return strcmp($a, $b);` - *Jein* on the bool-as-number issue. If it simplifies code to that extreme, I'd use the characteristics of a dynamically typed language and go for it. Seems simpler and less error prone than multiple nested `if..else` statements.

Comment: 1: You have is_dir($a) and is_dir($b) backwards. And 2: `return ($cmp = is_dir($b) - is_dir($a)) ? $cmp : strcmp($a, $b);` Booyah!

Comment: *Actually*... I'd prefer an explicit `if..else` here with nice indentation and curly braces (omitted above for formatting reasons)... ;)

Comment: What? First too many ifs, then not enough? Well, I would prefer if PHP weren't the only language left without lambdas

Comment: Hehe. ;P Readability is a tricky art. Too dense code is just as bad as too verbose code...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scandir` or `DirecotryIterator` and check every element if it is file or directory but the function you are looking for does not exist. How would you know if value in array is file of directory? You would have to check it anyway.

Comment: `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` That is all.